# Does this limit of measures exist?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $T:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is a differentiable transformation. Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Denote by $B(x,r)$ the open ball centred at $x$ with radius $r$. Now let $\mu$ be another measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mu(B(Tx,r))}{\lambda(B(Tx,r))}=a<\infty$$
Does it then follow that $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{\mu(T(B(x,r)))}{\lambda(T(B(x,r)))}=a$$
or that this limit even exists?

EDIT: I can now see that it is true for almost all $x$ if we assume that  $T$ is one-to-one. Do we need this assumption though? What about an "awkward" $T$ which isn't one-to-one on any open ball?

EDIT: I can see that these examples break down when $\lambda(T(B(x,r)))=0$. So what if we define $$Q(r)=\frac{\mu(T(B(x,r)))}{\lambda(T(B(x,r)))}$$ whenever $\lambda(T(B(x,r)))\neq0$ and $Q(r)=a$ otherwise. What can we say about the limit of $Q(r)$ as $r\rightarrow 0$? Would this allow me to weaken the assumptions to $T$ being differentiable only at $x$?

Comment: what is $m$ in your formulas?

Comment: A mistake sorry!

Comment: Since the first condition is about regularity of $\mu$ at $Tx$ and the second also the regularity of $T$ at $x$, I suspect the second limit need not to exist. However, I have no example at hand.

Comment: notice that $\lambda(TB(x,r))$ might be 0. you should at least make similar assumption like in the transformation formula.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments. It is valid for almost every $x$, if $\mu$ has a Lebesgue density and $T$ satisfies the conditions for transformation formula. Just look up Lebesgue differentiation theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: You need to be more specific about the awkwardness of $T$. The second limit is not defined for any constant function for example. Please give a specific example.